# How to override a class in liferay 7/DXP. the class inside the modules/ foundation?

Tags: liferay, liferay-dxp

Is there any way to override class inside the modules/foundation in liferay DXP?

Answer (score 0):

Liferay 7 design is more over extensible than override. Instead of overriding something extend the functionality or replace with another module.

Here's are few samples which allow us to extend at different level.

https://github.com/liferay/liferay-blade-samples/tree/master/liferay-workspace/extensions

https://github.com/liferay/liferay-blade-samples/tree/master/liferay-workspace/overrides

Comment: how to change /osgi/marketplace/Liferay Foundation.lpkg inside that Portal-store .class files..

Comment: what you exactly want to change?

Comment: Need to change s3store.java ?